# c++ - enum to char * - This answerless q‌u‌e‌s‌t‌i‌o‌n was asked before the time of boost

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, logic

I knew that similar duplicate questions are available in SO. But those questions were not discussing that much about boost. I got the type of enum using

`(boost::any).type().name()`

`Enum Example{ex1,ex2};`

The above code will produce

`Example`

But I want to get the exact phrase like "ex1". I am using VC++ now. There I need to check each and every enum to populate some message about API call's status. I am very new to boost, but now itself I can fell the (flex|a)ibility of the boost. So there must be a easy method which has the ability to do this.

Thanks Prabhakaran(answers){}

Answer (score 1):

Boost has no magical ways of doing this. For types, it can rely on RTTI, a basic C++ feature. But enumerator names are lost once a program is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be what you are looking for?

> Enum to String and Vice Versa in C++
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/StringizingCppEnums.aspx

Comment: I don't like to use define, and that code is for user defined enums. I need general case like I want to refer windows enums which were not user defined

Comment: enumerator names are known at run-time in any means unless you save it somewhere yourself.

Comment: @prabhakaran: Yet this is the canonical and reliable solution to this exact use case. Why don't you like to use #define?

Comment: @Tomalik Because defines are not that much programatical way(blind copy). It falls in the category of trick rather than programming way